# Disambiguate base class when calling non-virtual member

Tags: c++, c++14, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
struct Top {
    void foo();
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct Mid1: Top {
    virtual void bar() override { }
};
struct Bot1: Mid1 { };

struct Mid3: Top {
    virtual void bar() override { }
};

struct Bot3: Mid3, private Bot1 {
    using Mid3::bar;
    using Mid3::foo;
};
```

And the following snippet:

```
Bot3 b;
b.foo(); // does not compile
b.bar(); // compile
```

The error is:

> test.cpp:28:5: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'Bot3' to base class 'Top':
>
> ```
> struct Bot3 -> struct Mid3 -> struct Top
>
> struct Bot3 -> struct Bot1 -> struct Mid1 -> struct Top
>
> b.foo();
> ^
> ```

Is there a simple way to tell the compiler to use the first "conversion" sequence? `using Mid3::foo;` have no effects here (standard behaviour).

I know I can define `foo()` in `Bot3` and simply call `Mid3::foo()`, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: You have a diamond (or actually a pentagon I guess), so `Mid1` and `Mid3` need to use virtual inheritance to disambiguate which "path" to take to get to `Top::foo`

Comment: @0x5453 I don't want virtual inheritance here, I want a `Bot3` instance to "contain" two `Top` instances, one for `Mid3` and one for `Bot1`, and a call to `Bot3{}.foo()` to call `foo()` on the `Top` instance from `Mid3`, similarly to what would happens if I had define `void foo() { Mid3::foo(); }` inside `Bot3`.

Comment: As much as I love inheritance, this cries for composition.

Comment: @lorro Unfortunately the final code is more  complex - Bot3 inherits from multiple class, all of which except one (Mid3 here) inherits virtually from a base class (which is not Top in the example), and I need to be able to inherit from Bot3 in a virtual way. Each class has its own Top, but all the share a common TopPrime (share in the sense of virtual inheritance). I certainly don't claim this is the best design but it is the one I have to work with...

Answer (score 1):

Ambiguous situations are *ambiguous*. C++ doesn't allow you to have the "first" take priority; you must explicitly disambiguate the call each time.

Or just make a function in the derived class which forwards to the right base class function.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you can give the compiler some help by letting it know which branch of the inheritance tree it should descend to call your base class method.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Bot3 b;
    static_cast<Mid3*>(&b)->foo();
    return 0;
}
```